# initialization of C structure array

Tags: c, unix

unix 6th source code. Very old.

conf.h

```
 struct bdevsw {
   int (*d_open)();
   int (*d_close)();
   int (*d_strategy)();
   int *d_tab;
 } bdevsw[];
```

conf.c

```
 int (*bdevsw[])(){
    &nulldev, &nulldev, &rkstrategy, &rktab,
    &nodev, &nodev, &nodev, 0,
    0
 }
```

My question why not the initialization just reads,

```
 bdevsw[] = {......}
```

Comment: UnixV6 was introduced in 1975, *long* before even C89. Did C even *have* structure initialisation of the type you show  back then? :-)

Comment: At a first glance, the second parenthesis in the initialization stmt makes it look like a function which confuses me.

Comment: If this is K&R style C it is going to be *very* quirky looking compared to modern C.

Comment: Seems like some spawn-off from K&R even before there was a de facto standardization... Why do you need to understand this old crap anyway? It went obsolete somewhere around 1978.

Comment: V7 cleaned this up a little; it had `struct bdevsw bdevsw[] = { ... }`

Comment: regarding: `struct bdevsw {
   int (*d_open)();
   int (*d_close)();
   int (*d_strategy)();
   int *d_tab;
 } bdevsw[];`  do NOT place data declarations in a header file (place the data declaration in the *.c source file and only the struct type definition in the header file)  Otherwise, when this header is included in more than one source file there will be more than one instance of the data.  Also, this declares an array with no length value, which is not allowed in C.  At best the compiler will define a point to the struct type.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick By perusing the code, I conclude at the time of V6, there was no syntax to initialize structure array.Thus, it borrows the definition of function. The end result is the same

Answer (score 2):

All the information gathered for this answer is from my trusted copy of the Lions' Commentary book. It's a good resource for the *very* early UNIX code.

If you pump that monstrosity of a declaration into [cdecl](https://cdecl.org), you'll see that its purpose is to:

> declare `bdevsw` as array of pointer to function returning `int`.

Hence it's not code at all<sup>(a)</sup>, rather it's the array definition for the functions, one per device, pretty much the same as your suggestion would be.

The reason it's not in the header file is probably for the following reasons.

---

First, the `conf.c` file is actually [auto-generated](https://unixarchive.cn-k.de/PDP-11/Documentation/v6_setup.html) by `mkconf`, as that's the file that contains the device details (block and character devices, held in `bdevsw` and `cdevsw`) for a given UNIX system.

As an autogenerated file, it makes sense to break apart the declarations of the data types (which are consistent across different systems) and the definitions of the arrays (which do change per system). The comment at the top of this file state that it, and `low.s`, are the result of `mkconf`.

---

Second, there are quite a few C files that include `conf.h`. For example, `bio.c` (block I/O), `sys3.c` (filesystem calls), `fio.c` (file calls), and `alloc.c` (very early initialisation to read the root super block).

So, if the array was defined in the header file (presumably as `static` to prevent double definition), each source file would basically have it's *own* copy, wasting precious space. By defining it in `conf.c`, there's *one* copy shared amongst everyone.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Your comment that:

> the second parenthesis in the initialization stmt makes it look like a function

is understandable and, in this case, it *does* represent a function call. But only insofar that it's an array of pointers *to* functions, not an actual function *definition.*

Comment: By saying "break apart the declarations of the data types (which are consistent across different systems) and the definitions of the arrays (which do change per system).", which part is data type? Is it int or function?

Comment: @CCNA, the declaration is what you see in the header, it declares `bdevsw` as being of the structure type (declare = "this exists but I don't know its value yet"). The definition in the C file (define = "this is its value") is the bit you asked about.

Comment: I misunderstood what you mean by "definition of the arrays". You meant data declaration vs. type definition.

Comment: @CCNA, I often find it's useful to think of the distinction thus: Declaration declares that something exists without defining what its value is (though, by necessity, you have to say what *type* it is). That's what's in the header, it states that `bdevsw` exists but does not create it. Definition, on the other hand, creates it, and that's what you have in the C file.